# Main path analysis in citation network using igraph in R

Tags: r, igraph

Is anyone familiar with a way to implement Main Path Analysis (Hummon and Doreian 1989) using igraph in R?

Here is an example from the original Hummon and Doreian article. It tracks the citations from 40 journal articles on DNA. Arrows move forward in time (information from old articles 'flows to' new ones).

```
dna_edges <- data.frame(from=c(1,2,3,3,3,5,6,9,12,12,15,15,10,11,11,13,14,14,14,16,16,17,19,19,19,19,19,20,20,20,20,24,24,21,21,23,22,26,27,29,30,31,31,32,32,32,33,33,35,35,36,36,36),
                    to=c(8,18,4,5,21,12,9,12,15,29,29,22,17,13,20,20,16,20,31,17,20,34,20,24,25,21,25,31,22,30,22,28,37,22,32,27,27,27,32,32,40,32,40,36,38,33,32,35,38,39,38,39,40))

dna_g <- graph_from_data_frame(dna_edges, directed=T)
plot(dna_g,
     layout=layout_with_sugiyama(dna_g,
                                 layers = V(dna_g)$name)$layout)
```

[image]

[Liu et al (2019)](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11192-019-03034-x) explain that in a citation network nodes can be one of 3 things:

1. Sources: are cited but cite no one
2. Sinks: cite others but are never cited
3. Intermediates: cite and are cited

So in this example, we have ten articles that are 'sources' and ten others that are 'sinks':

```
dna_sources <- V(dna_g)$name[which(degree(dna_g, mode="in")==0)] # sources
[1] "8"  "18" "4"  "34" "25" "28" "37" "40" "38" "39"
dna_sinks <- V(dna_g)$name[which(degree(dna_g, mode="out")==0)] # sinks
[1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "6"  "10" "11" "14" "19" "23" "26"
```

A Main Path is the most used path connecting a source to a sink. Search Path Count (SPC) is one of the ways to do it.

> "A citation link’s SPC is the number of times the link is traversed if
> one runs through all the possible citation chains from all the sources
> to all the sinks in a citation network. To find SPC for a specific
> link, one needs to enumerate all the possible citation chains that
> emanate from all the sources and terminate at all the sinks" (Liu et al. 2019: 381)

So it would seem that in order to proceed one needs to (i) pick a source-sink pair, (ii) find all paths connecting this two nodes and add +1 weight to each edge when it is crossed, (iii) repeat for the other source-sink pairs.

Any thoughts on how to perform (i) to (iii)?

Comment: please provide more information regarding "main path analysis". What is that? How it works? An example with explanation?

Comment: i've added some more details based on the literature

Comment: What do you mean "weight to each edge when it is crossed"? Do you mean two paths share the same edge?

Comment: Yes. In the example on the plot, there are, for instance, several paths leading from source 3 to sink 39 (3-21-32-36-39, or 3-21-32-33-35-39, etc) [the viz is not so clear: the original H&D article is cleaner]. The aim would be that each edge gets a point or something if it lies on a source-sink path. So we see that the edges 3-21-32 would get more points (a 'higher weight') because they are present in more paths; a 'mandatory route', of sorts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## SPC

The following function implements SPC.

```r
spc <- function(g) {
  linegraph <- make_line_graph(g)
  source_edges <- V(linegraph)[degree(linegraph, mode = "in") == 0]
  sink_edges <- V(linegraph)[degree(linegraph, mode = "out") == 0]
  tabulate(
    unlist(
      lapply(
        source_edges,
        all_simple_paths,
        graph = linegraph,
        to = sink_edges,
        mode = "out")))
}
```

## Main path search

The following function finds a main path. Do note that there may be other main paths, if there are several main paths with the same total SPC value. This function returns the first main path it finds.

```r
main_search <- function(g) {
  linegraph <- make_line_graph(g)
  V(linegraph)$spc <- spc(g)
  source_edges <- V(linegraph)[degree(linegraph, mode = "in") == 0]
  sink_edges <- V(linegraph)[degree(linegraph, mode = "out") == 0]
  paths <- unlist(
    lapply(
      source_edges,
      all_simple_paths,
      graph = linegraph,
      to = sink_edges,
      mode = "out"),
    recursive = FALSE)
  path_lengths <- unlist(lapply(paths, function (x) sum(x$spc)))
  vertex_attr(linegraph, "main_path") <- 0
  vertex_attr(
    linegraph,
    "main_path",
    paths[[which(path_lengths == max(path_lengths))[[1]]]]) <- 1
  V(linegraph)$main_path
}
```

## Testing

[image: Wikipedia main path figure]

[The Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_path_analysis#Search_path_count_(SPC)) for main path analysis has a figure of a graph with SPC values attached to all edges. You can see a copy of this figure above. I transcribed this graph into R, including the expected SPC values and (global) main path.

```r
library(tibble)

wikipedia_g <- graph_from_data_frame(
  tibble::tribble(
    ~from, ~to, ~expected_spc, ~expected_main_path
    "A", "C", 2, 0,
    "B", "C", 2, 0,
    "B", "D", 5, 1,
    "B", "J", 1, 0,
    "C", "E", 2, 0,
    "C", "H", 2, 0,
    "D", "F", 3, 1,
    "D", "I", 2, 0,
    "J", "M", 1, 0,
    "E", "G", 2, 0,
    "F", "H", 1, 0,
    "F", "I", 2, 1,
    "G", "H", 2, 0,
    "I", "L", 2, 0,
    "I", "M", 2, 1,
    "H", "K", 5, 0,
    "M", "N", 3, 1),
  directed = TRUE)
```

The expectation is that all values output by the `spc` function equal the `expected_spc` values, which is the case. Similarly, the values for `expected_main_path` should match those output by `main_search`, which is the case as well.

```r
all(E(wikipedia_g)$expected_spc == spc(wikipedia_g))
# TRUE
all(E(wikipedia_g)$expected_main_path == main_search(wikipedia_g))
# TRUE
```

Comment: thanks @Tim. In this case also, to find the main path, one still needs a function to show which path has the highest summed total, right?

Comment: @Rafael You are right. I updated my answer with an additional function that searches the main path.

Comment: the 2 functions do the job very well. After trying it out a bit, I find that after 100 nodes the computational cost becomes too high. Would you have any thoughts on how to parallelize the process?

Answer (score 3):

## Update

If you want to find out which path gives the highest sum weight, you can try the code below

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(edgelst)
asp <- unlist(
  sapply(
    names(dna_sources),
    function(s) {
      all_simple_paths(g, s, names(dna_sinks))
    }
  ),
  recursive = FALSE
)

path_weight <- sapply(
  asp,
  function(p) {
    v <- names(p)
    sum(merge(
      edgelst,
      data.frame(from = head(v, -1), to = tail(v, -1))
    )$weight)
  }
)

max_cum <- max(path_weight)
path_max <- asp[path_weight == max_cum]
```

and you will see

```
> max_cum
[1] 30

> path_max
$`61`
+ 7/33 vertices, named, from a74a1fe:
[1] 6  9  12 29 32 36 39

$`111`
+ 6/33 vertices, named, from a74a1fe:
[1] 11 20 31 32 36 39
```

---

Here is a brute-force method using `all_shortest_paths` (if you don't need all paths being the shortest, you can use `all_simple_paths` instead)

```
dna_g <- graph_from_data_frame(dna_edges, directed = T)

dna_sources <- V(dna_g)[degree(dna_g, mode = "in") == 0]
dna_sinks <- V(dna_g)[degree(dna_g, mode = "out") == 0]

edgelst <- aggregate(weight ~ ., cbind(
  do.call(
    rbind,
    unlist(sapply(
      dna_sources,
      function(s) {
        # asp <- all_simple_paths(dna_g, s, dna_sinks) ## if we apply `all_simple_paths`
        asp <- all_shortest_paths(dna_g, s, dna_sinks)$res
        lapply(asp, function(p) {
          v <- names(p)
          data.frame(from = head(v, -1), to = tail(v, -1))
        })
      }
    ), recursive = FALSE)
  ),
  weight = 1
), sum)

dna_df <- merge(dna_edges, edgelst, all = TRUE)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(dna_df, directed = TRUE)

plot(g, edge.label = dna_df$weight)
```

where

```
> dna_df
   from to weight
1     1  8      1
2     2 18      1
3     3  4      1
4     3  5     NA
5     3 21      3
6     5 12     NA
7     6  9      3
8     9 12      3
9    10 17      1
10   11 13     NA
11   11 20      4
12   12 15     NA
13   12 29      3
14   13 20     NA
15   14 16      1
16   14 20     NA
17   14 31      3
18   15 22     NA
19   15 29     NA
20   16 17      1
21   16 20     NA
22   17 34      2
23   19 20      2
24   19 21      2
25   19 24      2
26   19 25      2
27   19 25      2
28   20 22     NA
29   20 22     NA
30   20 30      2
31   20 31      4
32   21 22     NA
33   21 32      5
34   22 27     NA
35   23 27      3
36   24 28      1
37   24 37      1
38   26 27      3
39   27 32      6
40   29 32      3
41   30 40      2
42   31 32      4
43   31 40      3
44   32 33     NA
45   32 36     11
46   32 38      7
47   33 32     NA
48   33 35     NA
49   35 38     NA
50   35 39     NA
51   36 38     NA
52   36 39      7
53   36 40      4
```

and you will get a plot like below
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot @ThomasIsCoding, I believe this should work. I will test it and get back it to you

Comment: @Rafael You are welcome and good luck to your trial.

Comment: could this be extended to indicate which of the paths has the highest summed weight?

Comment: thanks again Thomas. I got a slightly different result replicating your code (max_cum=307) but it seems that it already does the job. Cheers

Comment: @Rafael I think it depends on how you define the path, i.e., shortest path or simple path. They will give different weights to edges. I used `all_simple_path` here. Maybe you can try `all_simple_path` instead (see the commented line in my code)

Comment: This is extremely helpful. Thank you for writing this up, @ThomasIsCoding.